# Terminate running threads on JFrame close

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, windowlistener

How do I invoke extra operations when the user closes a `JFrame` window? I have to stop existing threads.

As I understand it, `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` causes the frame to be closed and its thread to be stopped. Should threads be closed after `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`?

Client:

```
static boolean TERMINATE = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
// some threads created
 while(true) {

                if(TERMINATE){
                         // do before frame closed
                    break;
                         }
              }

}
    private static JPanel startGUI(){
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel gui = new JPanel();
             f.add( gui);
             f.setSize(500,500);
             f.setVisible(true);
             return gui;
        }
```

---

I need to close sockets the thread's working with. What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: See also [*§12.8. Program Exit*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.8).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` actually terminates the JVM ([`System.exit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)). All running threads will automatically be stopped.

If you want to perform some action when a `JFrame` is about to close, use a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

```
JFrame frame = ...
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // close sockets, etc
    }
});
```

Comment: This is true if the user presses the window close icon at the top left of the JFrame, but isn't true if the JFrame closes by calling `dispose()` on it, not if a non-daemon thread is running.

Answer (score 3):

- You have to add a `WindowListener` to the `JFrame`.
- Inside the `windowClosing` method, you can provide required code.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    public ClosingFrame() {
        File.add(Exit);
        MenuBar.add(File);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
        WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                        "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (confirm == 0) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        };
        frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirm == 0) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClosingFrame cf = new ClosingFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default close operation on the JFrame

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: this method don't kill the thread, they still stay alive